# C++ x doesnt loop increament

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop, cout

I have a task from my teacher,like :
x^2 + y^3 = z

x filled only with odd
y filled only with even

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int x,y,z;

int main(){
   for (x=1;x<=20;x++){
      if ((x%2==1)&&(y%2==0)){
         for (y=1;y<=20;y++){
            if ((x%2==1)&&(y%2==0)){
               z = (x*x) + (y*y*y);
               cout << "x^2 + y^3 =" <<z <<"\n";
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I try to make my own code like above ,but the only one loop is Y , x stand still with 1.

I want to make x to be looping too. What should i do?

My output expectation would be like :

```
1^2 + 2^3 = 9
3^2 + 4^3 = 71
5^2 + 6^3 = 241
7^2 + 8^3 = 561
9^2 + 10^3 = 1081
11^2 + 12^3 = 1849
13^2 + 14^3 = 2913
15^2 + 16^3 = 4321
17^2 + 18^3 = 6121
19^2 + 20^3 = 8361
```

PS. Im sorry with my bad english :D

Comment: Besides  the atrocious indentation, you should solve this by using a *debugger*. With a debugger you can step through code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `y` has static storage duration, so it's zero initialized.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yeah just saw that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so should i go to scan variable 1st after "IF-STATEMENT" ? but i dunno what i should use to scan variable on c++

Comment: @FahmyArsyaad The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have:

```
int main(){
   for (x=1;x<=20;x++){
      if ((x%2==1)&&(y%2==0)){
         for (y=1;y<=20;y++){
            if ((x%2==1)&&(y%2==0)){
               z = (x*x) + (y*y*y);
               cout << "x^2 + y^3 =" <<z <<"\n";
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is the first `if ((x%2==1)&&(y%2==0)){` check.

After the inner for loop is completed, the value of `y` will be 21. Hence, the above conditional evaluates to `false` no matter that the value of `x` is. As a consequence, the inner for loop is executed only once. You need to remove that first `if` statement.

```
int main(){
   for (x=1;x<=20;x++){
      for (y=1;y<=20;y++){
         if ((x%2==1)&&(y%2==0)){
            z = (x*x) + (y*y*y);
            cout << "x^2 + y^3 =" <<z <<"\n";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

Looks like you need much simpler code.

```
int main(){

   // Start with x = 1 and increment x by 2. It will be always be odd 
   for ( x = 1; x <= 20; x += 2 ){

      // No need to create another loop. y is simply x+1
      // Since x is odd, y will be even.
      y = x+1;

      // Compute the result and print it.
      z = (x*x) + (y*y*y);
      cout << "x^2 + y^3 =" << z <<"\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: I just tried ur solution but it results too many output. What i want is like : 
1^2 + 3^3 = 9
3^2 + 4^3 = 71
etc

Comment: x filled with odd and y filled with even until 20 iteration. Like the final output is 19^2 + 20^ = 8361

Comment: @FahmyArsyaad, what about`1^2 + 4^3 = 65`? Do you not want to see that?

Comment: Thank you so much my friend :") finally it solved :")))
Im sorry with my stupid question and (may-be) forced you

Comment: @FahmyArsyaad, you are welcome. I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Because y = 21 after the inside y loop.So the x loop will not be executed after . Hope it helpful.